# HTML full width image, fixed height

Tags: html, css, image, height, width

I am currently designing a simple web page which will consist of a logo, a horizontal navbar to the right of that, a full width image with a fixed height underneath and if on a certain page, an extra horiontal navbar underneath. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<img src="img/imgicon.jpg" />
<nav id="mainnav" style="float: right />
<img src="img/fixedimg" style="width: 100%; height: 30%;  />
<nav id="secondnav" />
```

The problem I have is that the fixed image is always full size and not fixed. I've tried using a parent container (div) and setting a fixed height on that, however the image always goes full size. The only solution I could find is setting the position of the image to absolute but then the nav bar underneath is hidden under the image, and I don't want to use 20 `<br>` to get it underneath.

What would be the best possible way to solve this?

Here's a snippet:

```css
body {
  font-family: cambria;
  margin: 0;
}
/*TOP NAVBAR */

#topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  height: 71px;
}
#topnav li {
  margin-top: 13px;
  float: right;
}
#topnav li a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
#topnav li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
.active1 {
  color: blue;
}
/*SECONDARY NAVBAR */

#secondnav {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666666;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #8c8c8c;
  width: 100%;
}
#secondnav li {
  float: left;
}
#secondnav li a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />
    <title>Website</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--LOGO-->
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 71px;">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Intel-logo.svg/2000px-Intel-logo.svg.png" style="float: left; margin-left: 150px; height: 71px; width: 220px;" />
      <!--MAIN NAV-->
      <ul id="topnav">
        <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="courseinfo.html">INFORMATION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 5%; width: 100%;">
      <img src="http://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Blue-Scratched-Textured-Background.jpg" alt="welcome" style="width: 100%; height: 5px%;" />
    </div>
    <!--SECONDARY NAV-->
    <ul id="secondnav">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

  </html>
```

As you can see from the snippet, even though the image is set to small it goes full size, as if I haven't set any attributes at all.

Comment: Could you post a [weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/) or snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Use css and give the img a class

```css
#fixed {
  width: 100% height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<img src="img/imgicon.jpg">
<nav id="mainnav" style="float: right;> 
<img class=" fixed; src="img/fixedimg,png">
  <nav id="secondnav"></nav>
```